# Firefox tab sequence opening

Tags: javascript, angular, firefox

I have grid with a lot checkboxes (per row).Then i check necessary records and  run javascript that opens each selected row in separate tab.

```
    SelectedRowsIds.foreach(function(id){
       window.open('url' + id, '_blank);
    });
```

**It works at IE and Google, but not at Firefox**

I found out that Firefox has different sequence tab opening behavior by default, but it's possible change it through browser settings.

1. Enter about:config in the Firefox address bar
2. Bypass any security warning
3. Locate the browser.tabs.insertRelatedAfterCurrent boolean
4. Change the value to false by double-clicking the value

**Q:** Can i somehow set ***browser.tabs.insertRelatedAfterCurrent*** to **false** programmatically with javascript?

**P.s** i had tried call `window.focus()`, but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config option `browser.tabs.insertRelatedAfterCurrent` only affects tabs opened by a link from the current tab (hence the "related").

It seems that in order to get around this default Firefox behavior an add-on like Tab Control is needed.